# how to use variable size array in android?

Tags: android, arrays, android-layout, android-activity, assets

I'm using string array which I'm passing to ArrayAdapter for spinner item.
my array size(usually less than 10) and values are variable (I'm taking it from asset file)

if I'm using this :

```
String[] arr = new String[10];
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        breader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(path)));
        int length = Integer.parseInt(breader.readLine());
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
            arr[i]=breader.readLine();

        initialize();
....
}

initialize(){    
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arr);
    spinner1.setAdapter(array);
}
```

it shows **NullPointerException** at spinner1.setAdapter(array); line.
can I reassign array length. I think its not possible.

Comment: Can you show your logcat?

Comment: instead of `Activity.this` use `YourActivity.this` like `MainActivity.this` and its better to use ArrayLis<String> instead String[], because you don't know exactly what is the size of your list

Comment: ArrayAdapter will accept ArrayList<String>?

Comment: yes ArrayAdapter Accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because of you add null when no data in last portion of array.
I mean there are 7 data in assest file and you move for loop 10 times so after 7 data Add there are null represent. so breader.readLine(); read null and add it to your string array and when you parse StringArray to Array Adapter there are null get on 8th position of array and nullpointer Exception fire.

So just check `breader.readLine()` != Null then add it to String of Array otherwise add some Temp text.

Or

You Also Use ArrayList instead of String[] Array.
ArrayList is dynamically Arraylist you can add data to list useing array.add(yourdata).

Thats it...

Comment: will ArratAdapter Accept ArrayList?

Comment: sorry it is not accepting ArrayList<String>. same error occurred.

Comment: have you change Activity.this to yourActivityname.this? in arrayAdapter.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake of initializing before the setContentView. Thanks for help. Thank you again